# Can't run any rake command: "ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I'm trying to run the rake migrate:db command and I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported. Use 'rdoc/task' (available in RDoc 2.4.2+) instead.
```

I tried doing other rake commands, and I got the same error. How can I fix this?

Comment: How about you edit your `Rakefile` and replace `rake/rdoctask` with `rdoc/task` as indicated in the error message?

Comment: You mean `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: How do I replace it? If I knew how to do it I wouldn't had asked in the first place...

Comment: And for those of you saying to read the error message, this is a known bug: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=649984

Comment: I resolved this by upgrading from rails 3.0.3 to rails 3.2.

Comment: I am having the same problem - "closed as not a real question" WTF? Its pretty basic: running a rake command gives this error message in Rails 2.

Comment: Voted to reopen due to @Mark-AR's response.

Comment: I've encountered the same problem in Rails 3.0.3--'rdoctask' isn't anywhere in the rakefile