# ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported. Use 'rdoc/task' (available in RDoc 2.4.2+) instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Seems the last post for this problem was closed for one reason or another so I'll try my luck...

I'm trying to run a simple "rake db:migrate" command. When I do, I get the error in the title.  Yes, the solution "appears" obvious but it's not because I don't my Rakefile does not contain any references to 'rake/rdoctask'. It seems to be coming from documentation.rake but when I try to change that file as recommended by the error, I get a different error. I have found a couple of posts declaring this to be a known issue but nothing I've found indicates how to fix or work around this.

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix it?  Below is the output from the rake command with a --trace:

```
$ rake --trace db:migrate
rake aborted!
ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported. Use 'rdoc/task' (available in RDoc 2.4.2+) instead.
    C:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rdoctask.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    C:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/tasks/documentation.rake:2:in `require'
    C:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/tasks/documentation.rake:2:in `<top (required)>'
    C:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/tasks.rb:15:in `load'
    C:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/tasks.rb:15:in `block in <top (required)>'
    C:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/tasks.rb:6:in `each'
    C:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/tasks.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    C:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:213:in `require'
    C:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:213:in `initialize_tasks'
    C:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:139:in `load_tasks'
    C:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
    C:/developer/skknobara/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
    C:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
    C:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
    C:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:583:in `raw_load_rakefile'
    C:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:89:in `block in load_rakefile'
    C:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
    C:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `load_rakefile'
    C:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:72:in `block in run'
    C:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
    C:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
    C:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
    C:/Programs/Ruby193/bin/rake:23:in `load'
    C:/Programs/Ruby193/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

---

I discovered that I had rails 3.0.3 in my Gemfile so I changed it to 3.2.9, but now when I run rake db:migrate I get:

```
rake aborted!
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rack":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 3.2.9) x86-mingw32 depends on
      rack (~> 1.4.0) x86-mingw32

    rack (1.2.5)
```

I'm not sure what the error means but "gem list rack" shows I have both 1.4.1 and 1.4.0 installed.  My Gemfile is pretty simple:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.9'
gem 'rack','< 1.4.1'
gem 'mysql2', '< 0.3'
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 62):

I had similar problem using rails 2.3.5 so as instructed in the trace message I have edited the Rakefile to require 'rdoc/task' instead of rake/rdoctask and installed rdoc gem.

If you are using rake version > 10.0.0 . please edit your Rakefile

from:

```
require 'rake'
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'rake/rdoctask'
require 'tasks/rails'
```

to:

```
require 'rake'
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'rdoc/task'
require 'tasks/rails'
```

If you don't want to edit the Rakefile you can switch back to older version of take like this

```
gem uninstall rake -v 10.0.3
gem install rake -v 0.8.7
```

Comment: Trying to upgrade rails 2 app in preparation to upgrade to rails 3 - and ran into this problem and after some hair pulling I tried this and it worked! Yea!

Comment: for me in the Rakefile I have `require 'rake'` not 'rake/rdoctask'... how do I fix this?  When I replace 'rake' with 'rdoc/task' I have the error now that `no such file to load -- rdoc/task`

Comment: I still got the error cannot load such file -- tasks/rails. Can you please help me giridharbandi ?

Comment: Instead of `rdoc/task` also try `rake/task`. It worked for my project (ruby 1.8.7)

Comment: @GerardWesterhof I still get uninitialized constant Rake::RDocTask

Comment: i have 3 versions of rake: `gem list | grep rake` = `rake (10.1.1, 10.1.0, 0.8.7)`.. i got a rails 2.3.5 project and another that's 3.0 that i'm working on at the same time.. how do i use a specific version of rake for each project (ie on command line?)

Comment: Uninstall not working for rake ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)

Answer (score 22):

I ran into similar problem when migrating my old app to rails 2.3.15. I solved it by installing an older version of rake, and uninstalling current 10.0.3 version:

```
gem install rake --version 0.8.7
gem uninstall rake --version 10.0.3
```

Comment: Thanks - just had to get an old app running on 2.3.5 and the default rake gem was 10.0.3.  Your answer solved it for me.

Comment: I removed the old versions of rails and rake that were installed via APT. These were causing a collision against the versions installed using gem... 
Now all seems to be working a lot more smoothly!

Answer (score 7):

I got it to work by putting

gem 'rake', '0.9.2.2'

in my Gemfile and then running rake as

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Comment: This is the answer to the original question. user1143970 is running rails 3.0 which doesn't have the Rakefile entries that GiridharBandi is describing (I don't know about 3.2). Also, danijel's solution won't work, at least it didn't for me, since thor seems to have a dependency on rake 10+. I started going down the route that Ben Atkin's but that gets messy quick. My guess is that @JstRoRR is also running something other than rails 3.0.

Answer (score 6):

I had to fix this while not breaking on places that have old rake but not rdoc installed. I added a begin...rescue clause:

```
begin
  require 'rake/rdoctask'
rescue
  require 'rdoc/task'
end
```

Answer (score 6):

I came across the same issue...I did what *GiridharBandi* mentioned above:

```
require 'rake'
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'rake/rdoctask'
require 'tasks/rails'
```

to:

```
require 'rake'
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'rdoc/task'
require 'tasks/rails'
```

Rake version 10.0.4 was there in the gem list but when I tried to uninstall, it said that rake is not installed. So I ignored this and proceeded to install rake 0.8.7. Once its installed, I installed rdoc

```
gem install rdoc

<= 1.8.6 : unsupported
 = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
 = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
>= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
```

and then everything started working just fine.

For rails 3.0.6, with the same kind of error:

```
ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported. Use 'rdoc/task' (available in RDoc 2.4.2+) instead.
```

I installed rake 0.9.2 and also rdoc. commented out the #require 'tasks/rails' and then everything started working. I think rake problem is resolved in rails > 3.2.9.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem recently.

Looks like the same problem as: [Can't run any rake command: "ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979550/cant-run-any-rake-command-error-rake-rdoctask-is-obsolete-and-no-longer-su)

I solved it by upgrading to Rails 3.2.9.

Comment: Okay, after adding that last edit and playing around a bit more, I managed to get all my versions straight and things are now working.  Seem my problems were a combination of going back to a project that was built using an older version of rails and my own lack of knowledge of the build process.  Learning lots...thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Oh my god, I was figting with this for almost hour and finally here is my case (may help someone :) ):
I got myself multiple rails versions installed
so I just uninstalled the latest one as I want to use the most edgy one (the 4.0.1 for now)

so :

```
$ gem uninstall rails
```

and I got this:

```
Select gem to uninstall:
 1. rails-0.9.5
 2. rails-4.0.0
 3. rails-4.0.1
 4. All versions
>
```

so I selected first two and that was it :)
now everything is OK 
hope this helps someone who got mysteriously stuck as me :(

Comment: That just helps in your special case. I encountered the same problem running only one single rails version.

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't the right way to do this, but I went into my Gemfile.lock file and changed my rake version back from 10.0.3 to 0.8.7. I'm running Rails 3.0.5 right now, and had updated briefly to 3.0.19 before reverting back. I believe that updated some gems and also made it so that the Rails gem was looking for the newest version greater than or equal to 0.8.7:

```
rails (3.0.5)
  actionmailer (= 3.0.5)
  actionpack (= 3.0.5)
  activerecord (= 3.0.5)
  activeresource (= 3.0.5)
  activesupport (= 3.0.5)
  bundler (~> 1.0)
  railties (= 3.0.5)
railties (3.0.5)
  actionpack (= 3.0.5)
  activesupport (= 3.0.5)
  rake (>= 0.8.7)
  thor (~> 0.14.4)
rake (0.8.7)
```

I also uninstalled 10.0.3:

```
gem uninstall rake --version 10.0.3
```

After that, everything is back to running as it should.

If I didn't roll back rails 3.0.19, then I would have kept using rake 10.0.3.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: This worked, but instead uninstalling 10.0.3 I run `bundle exec rake db:migrate` and it execute the task with the 0.8.7 version of the gem

Answer (score 1):

Like the original poster, I don't have a require of rake/rdoctask.
Upgrading my rails is not an option.  The answer is to keep your rake at 0.9.2.2 in your Gemfile.

Answer (score 1):

I run into this whenever I have a Bundler-based project and I'm using Ruby 1.9.***2***. Eventually I figure out that Bundler isn't managing the rdoc gem, and all I have to do to fix the problem is include rdoc in the Gemfile (or the gemspec if Gemfile is already configured to use it) and run `bundle install`.

I never seem to run into this with 1.9.3 or 2.0.0, only 1.9.2.