# Rake Abort! 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake

```
rake aborted!
ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported. Use 'rdoc/task' (available in RDoc 2.4.2+) instead.
```

Other questions suggest to modify the RakeFile, but in Rails 3.1.0 my rakefile looks like this:

```
1 #!/usr/bin/env rake
2 # Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
3 # for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be avai    lable to Rake.
4 
5 require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)
6
7 Store::Application.load_tasks
```

I dont know how to apply this answer: [ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported. Use 'rdoc/task' (available in RDoc 2.4.2+) instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117114/error-rake-rdoctask-is-obsolete-and-no-longer-supported-use-rdoc-task-ava)

Comment: Have you seen [ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported. Use 'rdoc/task' (available in RDoc 2.4.2+) instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117114/error-rake-rdoctask-is-obsolete-and-no-longer-supported-use-rdoc-task-ava)?

Comment: Yeah I included it in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies, I missed the link and comment that you don't know how to apply the suggested answer. The top voted answer in that link recommends that you open the `Rakefile` (located in the root of your rails project) and replace the line:

```
require 'rake/rdoctask'
```

... with:

```
require 'rdoc/task'
```

Give that a shot and see if it works. If not, we can always move onto some of the other suggestions and walk through them.

Comment: Thanks for responding. What I had trouble with was finding that line to change as it wasnt directly in my RakeFile.  I ended up finding it in .rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/tasks/documentation.rake  and the line switch worked

Comment: Is there a way to solve this without modifying Rakfiles of gems?