# How to solve rake db:migrate error in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, migration, rake

I am using the gem version 2.0.7 and rails version 3.0.7.

While i am running the rake db:migrate command it's throw the following error.

```
$ rake db:migrate --trace
rake aborted!
ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported. Use 'rdoc/task' (ava
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/rdoctask.rb:2:in `<top
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/tasks/documentation
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/tasks/documentation
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/tasks.rb:15:in `loa
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/tasks.rb:15:in `blo
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/tasks.rb:6:in `each
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/tasks.rb:6:in `<top
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:214:
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:214:
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:139:
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77:i
C:/Users/m/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/rail1/Rakefile:6:in `<top (requir
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `l
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `l
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:637:in `
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `b
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `l
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `b
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `r
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>
c:/Ruby193/bin/rake:23:in `load'
c:/Ruby193/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

How to solve it.

Please hlep me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The key part of the error message is this:

```
ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported. Use 'rdoc/task' (ava
```

If you search for the error message on StackOverflow or Google you will find at least three different questions on the same topic, among others this:

[ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported. Use 'rdoc/task' (available in RDoc 2.4.2+) instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117114/error-rake-rdoctask-is-obsolete-and-no-longer-supported-use-rdoc-task-ava)

The highest voted answer at the time of writing suggests editing your Rakefile from:

```
require 'rake'
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'rake/rdoctask'
require 'tasks/rails'
```

to:

```
require 'rake'
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'rdoc/task'
require 'tasks/rails'
```

---

If I were you, I would try to **upgrade Rails to 3.2** and see if the problem persists. If that is not an option the older questions will hopefully be of help.

Comment: I already tried that changes, But it's throw the same error.That's why i post that question

Comment: Right. For future reference, it makes it easier for people to help if you tell us in the question what you already have tried.

Comment: i changed the rake file like above mentioned. But it is not work.

Answer (score 0):

it can be solved it by installing an older version of rake, and uninstalling current 10.1.0 version:

```
gem install rake --version 0.8.7
gem uninstall rake --version 10.1.0
```