# how to use a specific ruby gem version using CLI and without using Bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have two rails projects on my box, one that is using rails 3.0 and as such Bundler handles all it's dependencies.. and the [other](http://projectfedena.org/) is a rails 2.3.5 that *doesn't* use bundler.

I'm getting this error when running rake:

```
ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported. Use 'rdoc/task' 
(available in RDoc 2.4.2+) instead.
```

doing a bit of [research](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14154890/766570) it turns out that I have two options

- edit the rake file to require rdoc/task rather than rake/rdoctask
- upgrade my rake gem to version >=10

if I run `gem list | grep rake` I get `rake (10.1.1, 10.1.0, 0.8.7)`, so naturally I have multiple versions of the same gem installed.. my question is how do i ask my rails 2.3.5 project to always use the 0.8.7 version of the gem?

Answer (score 1):

In environment.rb

```
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  #other code
  config.gem "rake", :version => "0.8.7"
end
```

Should work I think

Comment: the question was about using command line.. as i'm trying to use rake as a command line

Comment: tried that as well.. no luck.. i'm looking into [rvm gemsets](http://sirupsen.com/get-started-right-with-rvm/) right now

Comment: the rakefile won't help me on the cli

Comment: Yes, it will allow it once changed.