# Cannot create new Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I let a friend use my computer for a bit and I don't know what he did exactly, I know he played around with different versions of Ruby and Rails to view various apps. Now I can't even create a new app anymore; I get the following error

$ rails new jhg 
(in /Users/Naoki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rails-0.9.5)
rake aborted!
ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported. Use 'rdoc/task' (available in RDoc 2.4.2+) instead.

I'm brand new to rails and I can't find a solution to this problem, any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117114/error-rake-rdoctask-is-obsolete-and-no-longer-supported-use-rdoc-task-ava

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have multiple versions of Rails installed. Run `gem uninstall rails` and remove all the older versions.