# How to get past this error message?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, insoshi

I'm trying to install insoshi on my linux OS. However, I continue to get this error message that prevents me from installing it:

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- rake/rdoctask
/home/james/insoshi/Rakefile:8:in `<top (required)>'
```

How do I fix this error in order to install this application?

Answer (score 0):

Here's part of the Rakefile throwing that error:

```
# inoshi/Rakefile

require 'rake'
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'rake/rdoctask'
```

According to this answer:

[ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported. Use 'rdoc/task' (available in RDoc 2.4.2+) instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117114/error-rake-rdoctask-is-obsolete-and-no-longer-supported-use-rdoc-task-ava#14154890)

`'rake/rdoctask'` is deprecated; try `'rdoc/task'`.

FWIW, that project (https://github.com/insoshi/insoshi) has not been updated in six years. Just a suggestion that you might want to consider another tool. There may be a lot of error messages like this ahead.